# How to use gulp to run SASS transpiling?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I am new to gulp and want to use it to convert SASS to CSS. I have a `src` folder which has some scss files deep inside, and I want to mirror it to the public folder but as css files. This it the gulp code

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('src/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
});

//Watch task
gulp.task('default',function() {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.scss',['styles']);
});
```

but when I run `node gulp` the program just ends without any error or messages. Shouldn't it stay running to do te file listening (i.e. watch)? Also when I edit a .scss file, it does not create a public folder with the .css file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `gulp` no `node gulp`

You also need to add the `styles` task in the `default` one.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.scss',['styles']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'styles'])
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't log anything, and even when I edit a .scss file, it does not make a public folder with a css file in it.

Comment: Did you add the `public` folder? Try to use console.log inside your task `styles` if nothing is triggered your default task is the problem.

Comment: How do I add the public folder? I put a console.log(1) in the styles task, but it doesn't run.

Comment: You need to add a folder called `public` at the root (where is your gulpfile). Have tried to change CSS after the task run?

Comment: I created a public folder, and then tried it again, but still did not work.